# is it possible to access an instance of a non static class from another class

Tags: java, android

lets say I have classA and classB.

I know that I cannot just call a non static variable or method of classA from classB because the system doesn't know which instance of classA I want to use. but is there a way to specify which instance?

something like this: in class A I declare a static variable which whould hold the some sort of ID or context to the specific instance of the class

```
class classA{
  static Instance instance 

  onCreate(){
    instance = thisInstance();
  }

  Method1(){
   }
}
```

then in class B I would refer to that instance like this:

```
  ClassA.instance.method1();
```

is something like this possible? if so, what is the exact syntax?

[Bonus]: if no, what is the simplest way invoke a method in a class from another class? I assume some sort of event handling would be required. (I come from the embedded c world)

Comment: Get a reference to the other object and call a method on it? You might want to take a step back and go over some Java basics.

Comment: you may just want to use the `Singleton` pattern

Answer (score 1):

Declare a static member in ClassA

```
public class ClassA {
    public static ClassA object = new ClassA();

    public void doStuff() {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Then in ClassB

```
public void someMethod() {
     ClassA.object.doStuff();
}
```

Comment: No this not what I'm trying to do, I want to call a method in classA thats defined in classA, not a built in method such as toString.

Comment: this wouldn't work either, I want reference to the classA that was created by launching the app, not any arbitrary copy of classA. ClassA in my case is my main activity.

Comment: ClassA.object is a static variable. Static variables are initialized only once, at the start of the execution. It is a single copy to be shared by all instances of the class. You could make a private constructor in ClassA to ensure, ClassA.object is the only instance of ClassA in your app.

Answer (score 0):

In class B, you can define:

```
Class B {
  private static ClassA instanceA = null; // By making it null, you can later confirm that the instance was successfully passed by making sure instanceA != null.

  /**
  * This method allows you to pass the instance of ClassA into B so you can use its non-static methods.
  */
  public static void setInstanceA(ClassA instance) {
    instanceA = instance;
  }
}
```